# Why use 'return' inside an event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm borrowing some code ideas from the jQuery [lazyLoad](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/blob/master/jquery.lazyload.js) plugin, and was wondering if there is any real performance difference between the two ways of binding to the scroll event below.

In particular, why use return? Is there any benefit there?

```
 //how I wrote it
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
       base.update();
   });

  //lazyLoad version
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
       return base.update();
  });
```

To keep it simple, I'm not throttling the scroll here...

Comment: performance, no. Funcionality, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `base.update()` sometimes returns `false`, then that'd have the effect of preventing the default action of the event if the value is returned by the handler. (I'm not 100% sure that preventing the default action of a "scroll" event actually works; I guess it might. It's certainly true for "click" and others like that.)

If `base.update()` doesn't return anything, then returning its return value will have no effect whatsoever. I seriously doubt that there'd be any detectable performance impact one way or the other.

Comment: To comment on the performance aspect, if you look at the [source code of `jQuery.bind`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L23-L25), you'll see that it's only a wrapper to the `.on()` method, resulting in no performance impact at all.

Comment: @PaulMougel oh yes, I wasn't even thinking about that difference between the two, and you're right of course.

Comment: @Pointy thank you -that makes perfect sense. And when I looked closer at the lazyLoad update() function, he is returning false sometimes

Comment: Actually, there is a difference between [`.on()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L757-L809) and [`.bind()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L23-L25). In `.on()` you can [specify a selector](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to select the descendants. In `.bind()` the selector is always `null`.